# How to unit test dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Below is the method code :-

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Product_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products)
    {
        if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                ProductDto target = ProductService.GetProduct(product.productId);
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                if (target != null)
                {
                    CategoryDto dto = new CategoryDto
                    {
                        ChangeDate = now,
                        CreateDate = now,
                        FKChangedBy = 1,
                        FKCreatedBy = 1,
                        FKPhoneTypeID = 2, phone.SelectedTelephoneType),                            
                    };
                    ProductService.UpdateProduct(dto);
                }
            }
        }


        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());

    }
```

> > In the above method ProductService is the dependency of that method.Which is firing in loop.And i am mocking my both of the dependency methods "GetProduct" and "UpdateProduct".But as i am mocking it(eg,GetProduct),so when that method execute it always return null that's why the other section the :-

```
target != null
```

not executing.Can anyone suggest me the way to test it ? Also how i can test the dependencies which are calling in loop ?

Below is the unit test method :-

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Product_Update_PostTest_Test()
    {
        //Act
        Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest request = new Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest();
        var ID = 1;

        //mock the dependencies
        _productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetProduct(ID)).Returns(_productDto);
        _productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.UpdateProduct(_categoryDto));

        //Arrange
        var actual = _productController.Product_Update(request, _productViewModelList) as JsonResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(JsonResult));            
        Assert.IsTrue(_productController.ModelState.IsValid);
        Assert.AreEqual(null, ((Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult)(actual.Data)));
    }
```

Comment: How do you instantiate the productService in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductService` mock is setup here:

```
_productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetProduct(ID)).Returns(_productDto);
_productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.UpdateProduct(_categoryDto));
```

But as far as I can see, you're not actually telling your Controller class to use that mocked instance in your tests - do you have more setup that isn't shown here?

Comment: ,actually i am not getting the proper way to mock the dependency which is calling withing loop.Can you suggest me the best way for it ?

Comment: I think that's your answer.  You have code which uses a `ProductService` (`ProductDto target = ProductService.GetProduct(product.productId);`), and you have code that sets up expectations on a mock `ProductService` - but is your controller instance using your mock instance in your test?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to dependency inject the ProductService into your Controller. Try debugging  the controller and check if the ProductService is a proxy object that MOQ has created. You could use any DI framework like Spring.Net, MS Unity etc.

This is what I absolutely love about unit testing. It subtly enforces you to redesign and for all the right reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to instantiate you product service:

```
var _productServiceMock = new Mock< IProductService >();
```